# Find Count With Pivot Data SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot

I have been displaying Day Wise Attendance Data with Pivot SQL.

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2016-09-26' 
declare @enddate datetime = '2016-10-01'
declare @CompanyID int = 1

DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @COLUMN = N'';

DECLARE @DATERANGE TABLE (DateToCheck DATE) 
;WITH Temp
AS
(
    SELECT DT =DATEADD(DD,0, @startdate)  
    WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, @startdate) <= @enddate  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)  
    FROM Temp  
    WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <= @enddate  
)

INSERT INTO @DATERANGE 
SELECT DT From Temp

SELECT @COLUMN += N', T.' + QUOTENAME(DateRanges) FROM (SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATE, T.DateToCheck) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DateRanges FROM @DATERANGE T group by T.DateToCheck) AS A;

SET @SQL = '
DECLARE @DATERANGE TABLE (DateToCheck DATE) 
;WITH Temp
AS
(
    SELECT DT =DATEADD(DD,0, @startdate)  
    WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, @startdate) <= @enddate  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1, DT)  
    FROM Temp  
    WHERE DATEADD(DD, 1, DT) <= @enddate  
)

INSERT INTO @DATERANGE 
SELECT DT From Temp

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Email, T.DateToCheck, COALESCE(A.val, L.val, H.val, ''Absent'') val
    FROM AspNetUsers E
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT DateToCheck FROM @DATERANGE
    ) T--(DateToCheck)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ''Holiday'' val, HolidayDate, CompanyID FROM Holidays) H ON H.HolidayDate = T.DateToCheck AND H.CompanyID = @CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ''In : '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, MIN(AttendanceDateTime), 108) + '' / Out : '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(AttendanceDateTime), 108)  val, CAST(AttendanceDateTime As DATE) As AttendanceDate, UserID FROM Attendances GROUP BY CAST(AttendanceDateTime As DATE), UserID) A ON A.AttendanceDate = T.DateToCheck AND A.UserID = E.Id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ''Leave'' val, LeaveDate, UserID FROM LeaveApplications) L ON L.LeaveDate = T.DateToCheck AND L.UserID = E.Id
    WHERE E.CompanyID = @CompanyID
    ) T
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR DateToCheck IN (' + STUFF(REPLACE(@COLUMN, ', T.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')) P';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@startdate DATE, @enddate DATE, @CompanyID INT', @startdate, @enddate, @CompanyID
```

And below is the result set of how it's now

[image: Result Set]

Now I wish to add more field to the above SQL to display counts like PresentCount, AbsentCount, HolidayCount and LeaveCount

I have already written a SQL where I could easily display these counts but, I'm unable to make it work with the above PIVOT SQL.

So in this case, the result for first row would be PresentCount = 0, AbsentCount = 6, HolidayCount = 0 and LeaveCount = 0. For Row 2 it would be PresentCount = 4, AbsentCount = 2, LeaveCount and HolidayCount both is 0.

Comment: Maybe you could join counts table with your pivot?

Comment: @gofr1 You mean another cross join with same tables to select counts? I'll try that.

Comment: Why cross join? It cannot be inner or left joined?

Comment: Yes I did it with left join @gofr1. Thanks for the suggestion :) I'll post the answer here for future reference once I reach home :)